# Why is this label not centering?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, webforms

With ASP.NET Code :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Requests.aspx.cs" Inherits="Portal.Requests"
    MasterPageFile="Portal.Master" Title="Requests Log" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContentPlaceHolder">
    <div class="block" id="options">
        <h2>
            Requests Log
        </h2>
        <div style="padding: 12px 13px 0px 12px;">
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Search :" CssClass="label" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" Size="16" CssClass="textbox" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" CssClass="button" Style="float: right" runat="server"  Text="Search" OnClick="Search" />
        </div>
        <div style="width: 100%; text-align:center; color: #4E1329; font-size: smaller; float:none; display:inline;">
            you can search by acc no and username
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top: 10px; width: 250px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <asp:GridView ID="requestsGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="Horizontal">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstColumn" HeaderText="Who and When" HeaderStyle-Width="120px" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" HeaderStyle-Width="40px" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File" HeaderStyle-Width="25px">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDownload" runat="server" Text=".zip" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("Id") %>'
                                OnClick="Download" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Rendered :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
    Requests Log
</title><link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico" /><link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Stylesheet.css" /><meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1, user-scalable = yes" /><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" /></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="Requests.aspx" id="ctl01">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTM3NTI0NjYyOQ9kFgJmD2QWAgIDD2QWAgIDD2QWAgIHDzwrABECAA8WBB4LXyFEYXRhQm91bmRnHgtfIUl0ZW1Db3VudAIWZAEQFgAWABYAFgJmD2QWLgIBD2QWBmYPDxYCHgRUZXh0BRI1IGRheXMgYWdvIGJ5IG1hc2lkZAIBDw8WAh8CBQZHVTk5OTlkZAICD2QWAgIBDw8WAh4PQ29tbWFuZEFyZ3VtZW50BQExZGQCAg9kFgZmDw8WAh8CBRI1IGRheXMgYWdvIGJ5IG1hc2lkZAIBDw8WAh8CBQZHVTk5OTlkZAICD2QWAgIBDw8WAh8DBQE4ZGQCAw9kFgZmDw8WAh8CBRI1IGRheXMgYWdvIGJ5IG1hc2lkZAIBDw8WAh8CBQRDQUFSZGQCAg9kFgICAQ8PFgIfAwUCMTJkZAIED2QWBmYPDxYCHwIFEjUgZGF5cyBhZ28gYnkgbWFzaWRkAgEPDxYCHwIFBENBQVJkZAICD2QWAgIBDw8WAh8DBQIxM2RkAgUPZBYGZg8PFgIfAgUSNSBkYXlzIGFnbyBieSBtYXNpZGQCAQ8PFgIfAgUEQ0FBUmRkAgIPZBYCAgEPDxYCHwMFAjE0ZGQCBg9kFgZmDw8WAh8CBRI1IGRheXMgYWdvIGJ5IG1hc2lkZAIBDw8WAh8CBQRDQUFSZGQCAg9kFgICAQ8PFgIfAwUCMTVkZAIHD2QWBmYPDxYCHwIFEjUgZGF5cyBhZ28gYnkgbWFzaWRkAgEPDxYCHwIFBENBQVJkZAICD2QWAgIBDw8WAh8DBQIxNmRkAggPZBYGZg8PFgIfAgUSNSBkYXlzIGFnbyBieSBtYXNpZGQCAQ8PFgIfAgUEQ0FBUmRkAgIPZBYCAgEPDxYCHwMFAjE3ZGQCCQ9kFgZmDw8WAh8CBRI1IGRheXMgYWdvIGJ5IG1hc2lkZAIBDw8WAh8CBQRDQUFSZGQCAg9kFgICAQ8PFgIfAwUCMThkZAIKD2QWBmYPDxYCHwIFEjUgZGF5cyBhZ28gYnkgbWFzaWRkAgEPDxYCHwIFBENBQVJkZAICD2QWAgIBDw8WAh8DBQIxOWRkAgsPZBYGZg8PFgIfAgUSNSBkYXlzIGFnbyBieSBtYXNpZGQCAQ8PFgIfAgUEQ0FBUmRkAgIPZBYCAgEPDxYCHwMFAjIwZGQCDA9kFgZmDw8WAh8CBRI1IGRheXMgYWdvIGJ5IG1hc2lkZAIBDw8WAh8CBQRDQUFSZGQCAg9kFgICAQ8PFgIfAwUCMjFkZAIND2QWBmYPDxYCHwIFEjIgZGF5cyBhZ28gYnkgbWFzaWRkAgEPDxYCHwIFBENBQVJkZAICD2QWAgIBDw8WAh8DBQIyMmRkAg4PZBYGZg8PFgIfAgUSMiBkYXlzIGFnbyBieSBtYXNpZGQCAQ8PFgIfAgUEQ0FBUmRkAgIPZBYCAgEPDxYCHwMFAjI3ZGQCDw9kFgZmDw8WAh8CBRIyIGRheXMgYWdvIGJ5IG1hc2lkZAIBDw8WAh8CBQRDQUFSZGQCAg9kFgICAQ8PFgIfAwUCMjhkZAIQD2QWBmYPDxYCHwIFEjIgZGF5cyBhZ28gYnkgbWFzaWRkAgEPDxYCHwIFBENBQVJkZAICD2QWAgIBDw8WAh8DBQIyOWRkAhEPZBYGZg8PFgIfAgUSMiBkYXlzIGFnbyBieSBtYXNpZGQCAQ8PFgIfAgUEQ0FBUmRkAgIPZBYCAgEPDxYCHwMFAjMwZGQCEg9kFgZmDw8WAh8CBRIyIGRheXMgYWdvIGJ5IG1hc2lkZAIBDw8WAh8CBQRDQUFSZGQCAg9kFgICAQ8PFgIfAwUCMzFkZAITD2QWBmYPDxYCHwIFEjIgZGF5cyBhZ28gYnkgbWFzaWRkAgEPDxYCHwIFBENBQVJkZAICD2QWAgIBDw8WAh8DBQIzMmRkAhQPZBYGZg8PFgIfAgUSMiBkYXlzIGFnbyBieSBtYXNpZGQCAQ8PFgIfAgUEQ0FBUmRkAgIPZBYCAgEPDxYCHwMFAjMzZGQCFQ9kFgZmDw8WAh8CBRIyIGRheXMgYWdvIGJ5IG1hc2lkZAIBDw8WAh8CBQRDQUFSZGQCAg9kFgICAQ8PFgIfAwUCMzRkZAIWD2QWBmYPDxYCHwIFEXllc3RlcmRheSBieSBtYXNpZGQCAQ8PFgIfAgUGR1U5OTk5ZGQCAg9kFgICAQ8PFgIfAwUCMzVkZAIXDw8WAh4HVmlzaWJsZWhkZBgBBSljdGwwMCRNYWluQ29udGVudFBsYWNlSG9sZGVyJHJlcXVlc3RzR3JpZA88KwAMAQgCAWR+8m8SIKqbNyNbkrQBusmcNv8bCI0kMOXnKhs2eQPoUA==" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['ctl01'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.ctl01;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=QZPkRLZ3fUaN6VLGec8U1eb-7A0RmvYeX7AOUpyZg60IpqTruzWtehyWdkhkl9lfeQb8mEYo0i4n5nosbE2UTMyeu9sobarSJxcUx83SFPs1&amp;t=634768237750540983" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=gH6INTDR0ghdGy8187seiZld9-3hIDEUD4UZXxgbQNevT34BY6bPtKCTN86kvXWivVi5j4Mqk82c9kJeg-HGZ1gkOzd2OkB_H1SFfAw8T0nkn2J_yq_n7Tko8qp8GK6S2sFuEB6V36qw4i4I9UtNBZbY8gEyl8T9hpNAHBP1Ncc0EIlDqB6rGCKHSEZk0IqO0&amp;t=ffffffff940d030f" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');
//]]>
</script>

<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=SZ7Iu2p7Dx3sirGc0eodEyXdoKWQbBb85Myy8mEmJcXjSVSUbobpetDKV_2kbrQbyRsPhW2vufjIr6XDGEt7v-ukuTFQq2fNuNOHhcfIHAnmuQRWEXvmSJLpONklLNI8hQI7wxVjfx7Qg6EKoJkMvo4NWxeD_ZHIemwcs1W1QwmKgcv6UKwwzLFcarl9GeoC0&amp;t=ffffffff940d030f" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWGQKutYr8AwLI4arfCwLM08eUAgLIs/LdCwL5l4+IBwKqhYmXBwLjpMWIAgLsw7D4AQKN7v/UCQLu7ta3DALHv6LwCwKV16SoBwLup/DgBgLHs/78AwL4l5unDwKphZW2DwLipNGnCgLrw7yXCgKM7ov0AQLt7uLWBALGv66PBAKT17BRAuyn/AkCxbOKpg0C9pen0AiNJ9hTWsRav+IvckroC8qB9LGJ+gh+z0AvBqjhxR2QQA==" />
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ctl00$ScriptManager1', 'ctl01', [], [], [], 90, 'ctl00');
//]]>
</script>

    
    <div id="header" style="text-align:center;padding-top:5px;"> 
        <img id="uaLogo" alt="UA Logo" src="../UALogo.png" />
    </div>

    
    <div id="wrapper">
        
    <div class="block" id="options">
        <h2>
            Requests Log
        </h2>
        <div style="padding: 12px 13px 0px 12px;">
            <span class="label">Search :</span>
            <input name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$txtSearch" type="text" id="MainContentPlaceHolder_txtSearch" class="textbox" Size="16" />
            <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$btnSearch" value="Search" id="MainContentPlaceHolder_btnSearch" class="button" style="float: right" />
        </div>
        <div style="width: 100%; text-align:center; color: #4E1329; font-size: smaller; float:none; display:inline;">
            you can search by acc no and username
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top: 10px; width: 250px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <div>
    <table cellspacing="0" rules="rows" border="1" id="MainContentPlaceHolder_requestsGrid" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" style="width:120px;">Who and When</th><th scope="col" style="width:40px;">Type</th><th scope="col" style="width:25px;">File</th>
        </tr><tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td>5 days ago by masi</td><td>GU9999</td><td>
                            <a id="MainContentPlaceHolder_requestsGrid_btnDownload_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$requestsGrid$ctl02$btnDownload&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">.zip</a>
                        </td>
        </tr><tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td>5 days ago by masi</td><td>GU9999</td><td>
                            <a id="MainContentPlaceHolder_requestsGrid_btnDownload_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$requestsGrid$ctl03$btnDownload&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">.zip</a>
                        </td>
        </tr><tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td>5 days ago by masi</td><td>CAAR</td><td>
                            <a id="MainContentPlaceHolder_requestsGrid_btnDownload_2" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$requestsGrid$ctl04$btnDownload&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">.zip</a>
                        </td>
        </tr><tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td>5 days ago by masi</td><td>CAAR</td><td>
                            <a id="MainContentPlaceHolder_requestsGrid_btnDownload_3" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$requestsGrid$ctl05$btnDownload&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">.zip</a>
                        </td>
        </tr><tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td>5 days ago by masi</td><td>CAAR</td><td>
                            <a id="MainContentPlaceHolder_requestsGrid_btnDownload_4" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$requestsGrid$ctl06$btnDownload&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">.zip</a>
                        </td>
        </tr><tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td>5 days ago by masi</td><td>CAAR</td><td>
                            <a id="MainContentPlaceHolder_requestsGrid_btnDownload_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$requestsGrid$ctl07$btnDownload&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">.zip</a>
                        </td>
        </tr><tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td>5 days ago by masi</td><td>CAAR</td><td>
                            <a id="MainContentPlaceHolder_requestsGrid_btnDownload_6" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$requestsGrid$ctl08$btnDownload&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">.zip</a>
                        </td>
        </tr><tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td>5 days ago by masi</td><td>CAAR</td><td>
                            <a id="MainContentPlaceHolder_requestsGrid_btnDownload_7" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$requestsGrid$ctl09$btnDownload&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">.zip</a>
                        </td>
        </tr><tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td>5 days ago by masi</td><td>CAAR</td><td>
                            <a id="MainContentPlaceHolder_requestsGrid_btnDownload_8" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$requestsGrid$ctl10$btnDownload&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">.zip</a>
                        </td>
        </tr><tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td>5 days ago by masi</td><td>CAAR</td><td>
                            <a id="MainContentPlaceHolder_requestsGrid_btnDownload_9" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$requestsGrid$ctl11$btnDownload&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">.zip</a>
                        </td>
        </tr><tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td>5 days ago by masi</td><td>CAAR</td><td>
                            <a id="MainContentPlaceHolder_requestsGrid_btnDownload_10" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$requestsGrid$ctl12$btnDownload&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">.zip</a>
                        </td>
        </tr><tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td>5 days ago by masi</td><td>CAAR</td><td>
                            <a id="MainContentPlaceHolder_requestsGrid_btnDownload_11" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$requestsGrid$ctl13$btnDownload&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">.zip</a>
                        </td>
        </tr><tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td>2 days ago by masi</td><td>CAAR</td><td>
                            <a id="MainContentPlaceHolder_requestsGrid_btnDownload_12" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$requestsGrid$ctl14$btnDownload&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">.zip</a>
                        </td>
        </tr><tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td>2 days ago by masi</td><td>CAAR</td><td>
                            <a id="MainContentPlaceHolder_requestsGrid_btnDownload_13" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$requestsGrid$ctl15$btnDownload&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">.zip</a>
                        </td>
        </tr><tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td>2 days ago by masi</td><td>CAAR</td><td>
                            <a id="MainContentPlaceHolder_requestsGrid_btnDownload_14" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$requestsGrid$ctl16$btnDownload&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">.zip</a>
                        </td>
        </tr><tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td>2 days ago by masi</td><td>CAAR</td><td>
                            <a id="MainContentPlaceHolder_requestsGrid_btnDownload_15" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$requestsGrid$ctl17$btnDownload&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">.zip</a>
                        </td>
        </tr><tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td>2 days ago by masi</td><td>CAAR</td><td>
                            <a id="MainContentPlaceHolder_requestsGrid_btnDownload_16" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$requestsGrid$ctl18$btnDownload&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">.zip</a>
                        </td>
        </tr><tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td>2 days ago by masi</td><td>CAAR</td><td>
                            <a id="MainContentPlaceHolder_requestsGrid_btnDownload_17" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$requestsGrid$ctl19$btnDownload&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">.zip</a>
                        </td>
        </tr><tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td>2 days ago by masi</td><td>CAAR</td><td>
                            <a id="MainContentPlaceHolder_requestsGrid_btnDownload_18" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$requestsGrid$ctl20$btnDownload&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">.zip</a>
                        </td>
        </tr><tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td>2 days ago by masi</td><td>CAAR</td><td>
                            <a id="MainContentPlaceHolder_requestsGrid_btnDownload_19" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$requestsGrid$ctl21$btnDownload&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">.zip</a>
                        </td>
        </tr><tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td>2 days ago by masi</td><td>CAAR</td><td>
                            <a id="MainContentPlaceHolder_requestsGrid_btnDownload_20" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$requestsGrid$ctl22$btnDownload&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">.zip</a>
                        </td>
        </tr><tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td>yesterday by masi</td><td>GU9999</td><td>
                            <a id="MainContentPlaceHolder_requestsGrid_btnDownload_21" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$requestsGrid$ctl23$btnDownload&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">.zip</a>
                        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    


    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

css :

```
.block
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 440px;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888888;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #4e1329;
}

.block > *
{
    position: relative;
}

#options
{
    width: 273px;
    height: auto;
}
```

I get :

[image]

Why does the label/div (ive tried both) not center?

Comment: Can u post rendered code and css

Comment: Seems to be working. Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2c37L/

Comment: What width is this meant to be? Both `options` and `block` have a width assigned. Which width are you expecting to be used? What is the width of the area at the moment?

Comment: @DamienOvereem unfortunately it doesnt for me. Maybe because of the surroundings, but I had another label almost exactly the same which centered fine in similar surrounding divs. Thats why I cant understand why this is doing this.

Comment: @webnoob the width used is the #options one as thats more specific.

Comment: Are you able to recreate this using http://jsfiddle.net/? I can't see any problems providing the parent has a width and the child is set to 100% width.

Comment: Ok sorted it, remove display:inline from my post below. JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QCvaP/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
<div style="text-align:center; color: #4E1329; font-size: smaller; float:none">
    you can search by acc no and username
</div>
```

to

```
<div style="width: 100%; text-align:center; color: #4E1329; font-size: smaller; display:inline;">
    you can search by acc no and username
</div>
```

Note: You might also want to consider using CSS classes rather than inline styling.

**EDIT:** Ok after seeing your edit, your class `block` needs to set a width. In order for the text to be able to centre it needs to be 100% width. In order for 100% width to work, you need a parent with a width. If block has a width, please post the CSS for it.

**Edit - Final revision:**

`display:inline` is confusing it now. This and `float:none;` need removing.

```
<div style="width: 100%; text-align:center; color: #4E1329; font-size: smaller;">
    you can search by acc no and username
</div>
```

Fiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/QCvaP/1/

Comment: If that doesn't work, please post the code wrapping around your code.

Comment: Strange thing is, in jsfiddle ur solution shows as good. Yet chrome and ie still display it just like before...

Comment: Chrome and IE cache things well. Try spamming CTRL + F5 a few times.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I was zoomed in just a little bit, and thats what was causing it not to be centered.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it has to do with the surrounding div. If you put a div around it with a fixed with, everything seems fine.

Html:

```
<div style="width: 300px; border: 1px solid red;">
    <div style="padding: 12px 13px 0px 12px;">
        <span class="label">Search :</span>
        <input name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$txtSearch" type="text" id="MainContentPlaceHolder_txtSearch" class="textbox" Size="16" />
        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$btnSearch" value="Search" id="MainContentPlaceHolder_btnSearch" class="button" style="float: right" />
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:center; color: #4E1329; font-size: smaller; float:none">
        you can search by acc no and username
    </div>
</div>    ​
```

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/2c37L

Comment: To be honest the div around it already has a fixed width. (in css)

Answer (score 0):

Both divs are separate and above div has padding. Try adding padding to below div also like

```
style ="padding: 12px 13px 0px 12px;text-align:center;"
```

I hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your Div has one inline CSS and it says your div is `display:inline`. Is this for any special reason? Because if you remove the same you will find that Div become center aligned.

http://jsfiddle.net/7gdnH/1/